# Smalltalk / Squeak message handling method

Tags: class, smalltalk, message, squeak

A pretty short question - how is the message handling method named (the first method that is called on message passing), and in which class it is defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending a message to an object is handled by the VM, you won't find the specific method that handles it.

However, `ContextPart>>#send:to:with:super:` contains an implementation that should be identical to how the VM is implemented. In particular, it calls `Behavior>>#lookupSelector:`, where you can see the code that climbs up the inheritance hierarchy.